# What is the probability that $\max(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) < \min(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ where the $X_i$'s and the $Y_i$'s $\sim U[0, 1]$?

Tags: probability, order-statistics

What is the probability that $\max(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) < \min(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ where:

- $X_i \sim U[0, 1]$ and $Y_i \sim U[0, 1]$, and
- $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables?

I went as far as figuring out that the max and the min are beta-distributed, but I am not exactly sure how to go from there, and I am not even exactly sure whether this is the way to go. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose that the $~2n~$ numbers $~x_1, \cdots, ~x_{2n}~$ are going to be split into two sets of $~n~$ elements each.  Let $~a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n, ~b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n~$ represent these elements in strictly non-decreasing order, where (for example) $~a_n \leq b_1.~$  The probability that these $~2n~$ numbers are not all distinct numbers is $~0.$  There are $~\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}~$ equally likely ways of selecting $~n~$ elements from $~x_1, \cdots, x_{2n},~$ to form one of the two sets.  ...see next comment

Comment: What happens if the $~n~$ elements selected are not specifically equal to either $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}~$ or $~\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}~?$

Comment: The question does not even make sense without any independence assumptions.

Comment: @geetha290krm The question does however, make sense with the independence assumptions.  Further, in presenting Math problems there is a fairly widespread convention that problem composers generally intend that whether or not the events are independent, when no specification is given, is generally to be inferred from the problem's context.  In this case, since the problem is not solvable without the assumption of independence, it is reasonable to infer that the problem composer intended that the events are independent.

Comment: I don't think that sloppiness in the design of questions should count as a convention. Leaving out critical assumptions changes whether a question is answerable, or whether those seeking to answer it are needlessly wasting their time. With the addition of the assumption, I think it is a neat question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\max X_i$ and $m=\min Y_i.$ Then $\Pr(m>y)=(1-y)^n ,\Pr(M<x) =x^n, $ $$\Pr(M<m)= E(\Pr(M<m|m))=E(m^n)=n\int_0^1y^n(1-y)^{n-1}dy=nB(n+1,n)=\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}.$$